# Unable to reproduce duplicate record inserted in table issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table in sql server. When Inserting records into table, sometimes it inserts duplicate with same value in two rows but can't able to reproduce

Example: my 2 rows in table

```
C1   C2      C3   C4
157 Job157  158 Illumina Parking Building 1 

158 Job157  158 Illumina Parking Building 1
```

Comment: Well, it will be a good idea to post your query here so others can have a look at it.. otherwise no one will be able to help you

Comment: Hint: Identity Columns

Comment: thanks Amin,  Protected Sub btnSave_Click1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewState("JobId")) Then
            UpdateJobList()
            UpdateProjectMangement()
        Else
            InsertJobList()
        End If
        BindTopTab()
        lblSuccessMsg.Text = "Database updated successfully"
    End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this.

- Create a [unique constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on the table that covers all columns.
- Run your code in a debugger
- Set the debugger to break when you get an exception
- When it repeats, the debugger will tell you what code is dong the 2nd insert.
- Once you have fixed the problem, consider if you wish to keep the unique constraint

If it only repeats in production, then you need to do the above, but log all exception.

Lean about [primary keys](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/primary-key-primer-for-sql-server/), having one would very likely have made the 2nd insert fail and therefore shown the problem in your code.

*I expect that a page is being refreshed, or a button is being press more the once, but without seeing what is going on in the debugger, these are just guesses.*

Comment: Thank u so much for a advice. it happens once in 500 records approximately.Please help me try to find the issue soon.

Answer (score 0):

u need to check duplicate values in some field except  identity column 
u may b refreshing the page from which u are adding this data. put logic to check duplicate data in c2 column eg.

```
if not exists (select 1 from your table where c2=@"C2's parameter" )
begin
 insert operation
end
else
begin
raieerror already exists

end
```

hope u got my point